# async await is not working and console not returning an error

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am trying to make an API call with async await but it's not working and not giving errors
here I am trying to call getRace() which returns a promise so I am using await keyword here:

```
async function RaceInfo(){
     await getRace(raceID)
}
```

and then I call RaceInfo() and use then to handle the response:

```
RaceInfo().then(res=>{
        if(race.status === "in-progress") {
    renderAt('#leaderBoard', raceProgress(res.positions))
        }else if(race.status === "finished"){
    clearInterval(raceInterval) // to stop the interval from repeating
    renderAt('#race', resultsView(res.positions)) // to render the results view
    
        }
```

and then all of them need to be grouped inside a final promise to be called externally:

```
function runRace(raceID) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
    // TODO - use Javascript's built in setInterval method to get race info every 500ms
    
    async function RaceInfo(){
         await getRace(raceID)
    

    }
    RaceInfo().then(res=>{
        if(race.status === "in-progress") {
    renderAt('#leaderBoard', raceProgress(res.positions))
        }else if(race.status === "finished"){
    clearInterval(raceInterval) // to stop the interval from repeating
    renderAt('#race', resultsView(res.positions)) // to render the results view
    resolve(res)
        }

}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
})
    const raceInterval=setInterval(RaceInfo, 500);
})

}
```

console is not returning errors, what could be the issue?

Comment: You haven't returned a value from `RaceInfo`. Try `return await getRace(raceID)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't return anything from `RaceInfo`, and `race` is undefined in callback passed to `RaceInfo().then(...)`...

```js
function getRace(raceID) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve({status: "finished"}), 300);
  })
}

function runRace(raceID) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      // TODO - use Javascript's built in setInterval method to get race info every 500ms

      async function RaceInfo() {
          // Added return statement
          return await getRace(raceID);
      }

      RaceInfo().then(race => { // Changed paramter name 
          if(race.status === "in-progress") {
            console.log("race in progress");
            // renderAt('#leaderBoard', raceProgress(res.positions))
          } else if (race.status === "finished") {
            console.log("race in progress");
            // clearInterval(raceInterval) // to stop the interval from repeating
            // renderAt('#race', resultsView(res.positions)) // to render the results view
            // resolve(res)
          }
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })

    const raceInterval=setInterval(RaceInfo, 500);
  });
}

runRace(7);
```